# rails 4, collection_select, pass more than one attribute into params hash on form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm using collection_select to select an option from a drop down. When I submit the form I want to send multiple params into the params hash. In this case 'team_id' and 'team_name'. team_id is showing up in the params hash just fine. 'team_name' is the value which shows up in the drop down list itself.

view.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for @carpool do |f| %>
    <h3>Select Team</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.collection_select :team_id, @ts_teams ? @ts_teams : [], :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
    </div>
      <%= f.submit 'Create Carpool', :class => 'button left' %>
  <% end %>
```

params hash

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bdazhLNLZ0QunrpJT7Gu63ipX76WME+ENSxL/B0XGeFL/GP5nishozmQENe22aelfcnnhnPBr4B35MeRL+kJLQ==", "carpool"=>{"team_id"=>"1923565"}, "commit"=>"Create Carpool", "controller"=>"carpools", "action"=>"create"}
```

How can I pass team_name into the params hash?

Comment: What do you want to do with `team_name` in your controller method? Is there a reason you want to get it from the params hash?

Comment: Yup - I want to create a carpool object - I would like to set the 'name' property of the carpool object to the name of the team...team_name. Perhaps there is an easier way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want without jumping through flaming hoops by just creating an instance of Team (which you are probably already doing anyhow) and just getting the name directly.

In your controller method:

```
@team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
@team_name = @team.name
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however, The reason I am jumping through flaming hoops is so I don't have to create a Team model at all. I was doing this previously, and it worked of course. But required me to make an extra database query that is essentially pointless - because all I need is the name of the team.

Comment: What I wrote and what you had is "The Rails Way." Trying to avoid a small db transaction more or less amounts to a premature optimization at this point. The only alternatives I can think of include torturous manipulation of hidden fields with javascript and passing parameters in the url. I'm far from expert, however, so maybe someone else knows a magical way to wrangle the `text_method` out of the select and into the params hash.